Scale parentheses down to the size of a formula
I would like to typeset $(\cdot)$. Doing this doesn't look very good to me:

The parentheses are really tall relative to the little dot. I'd ideally like them to not extend below the extender height and extend only a little above the median, but definitely not above the cap height (keeping the interpunct relatively centered).

The \left and \right delimiters will stretch parentheses to the size of the formula inside, it appears that they will only scale up from the default size. Adding them causes no perceptible change. After looking at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Manual_sizing, I also tried \small and \tiny before each parenthesis, but seemingly to no effect.
I'd like some way to scale the parentheses down a little bit. I get that what is looks nice is subjective. I like what I've drawn in the mock up, but it doesn't have to be exactly that. I'll accept most any way to make them smaller, and if there's some way I could fiddle with the value until I feel it looks right that'd be great.

I wouldn't but {\scriptstyle(}{\cdot}{\scriptstyle)}
